# How to change python runtime in firebase functions

Tags: python, firebase, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I currently have python311, but it seems that it doesnt include ffmpeg. So I'm looking for ways to either change to python39 or figure out how to install and use ffmpeg.

When I try

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.run(shlex.split("ffmpeg -version")))
```

inside a firebase function, all I get is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'`
I've tried a few different places like /opt/bin/ffmpeg or ffmpeg/ffmpeg since I have have ffmpeg inside the folder functions, but it always the same error.

[Recommendation to use python39 for ffmpeg](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242685280?pli=1)

Edit: Things I found but couldnt get it to work:

`gcloud functions deploy <my function name> --runtime python39`

[Made this from gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

The console says that it can change the runtime environment, but I didn't find that to work.

The only thing that worked for me was to **delete the function and recreate it.**

```bash
gcloud functions delete <my function name>
```

I added `--gen2` and `--region=<my region>` since my function had specified those.

Then, you can go ahead and deploy again:

```bash
gcloud functions deploy <my function name> --runtime python39
```

And now my function is using the correct runtime and Ubuntu version.

See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/delete for a reference for deleting.